# How to prevent that the module version is updated if install/upgrade fail?

Tags: magento2, install-script

When you install/update a module, it is possible that for some reason the operation fails.

Using transaction, I managed to easily prevent updating/inserting the data by rollbacking in case of failure.

However, the module version in the `setup_module` table is still set by the installer. Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an exception after the rollback, otherwise Magento assumes the update was successful

Comment: OK. So if I guess correctly, the module being currently processed won't be updated at all, but those which were processed successfully just before (in the same setup:upgrade), will be updated?

Comment: yes, from my experience, this is how it works

Comment: Indeed. I tested your solution and this is what happen.